# Is designMode bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, designmode

In a previous post that I posted here, I got responses that contentEditable and designMode are bad practices. So I switched to TinyMCE, but that uses designMode as well... is there something bad about it?

Im using it for a Rich Text editor on my website fyi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were trying to tell you not to re-invent the wheel.

If you're using `designMode`, you probably want either a rich text editor (with toolbars) or a syntax-highlighting code editor.
In either case, you should reuse existing libraries rather than re-creating them from scratch.  (Rich text editors are *hard*, especially across browsers)

Comment: This man speaks the truth: writing a cross-browser rich text editor is deceptively hard. You can get something that nearly works quite simply, but the little things will kill you.